# PHP keeps saying invalid column name

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Here is my code:

```
<?php $txtCommentor = $_POST['txtCommentor'] //from form?>
<?php $txtComment = $_POST['txtComment'] //from form?>
<?php $jobno = $_GET['jobno'] //from URL?>

<?php
//Query and connect
$query = "INSERT INTO delivery_comments (commentor, comment, jobno) VALUES ($txtCommentor,$txtComment, $jobno) ";?>
<?php $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);?>
<?php echo $query?>
<?php
if( $results === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

When I run the page I get this these results:

```
INSERT INTO delivery_comments (commentor, comment, jobno) 
VALUES (frontdesk,bvhjfhj, 85450)
```

Then I get the error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'frontdesk'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'frontdesk'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'bvhjfhj'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'bvhjfhj'. ) )
```

Notice the echoed insert statement is first. This is correct. Then the rest of the error keeps telling me the data I want to insert is an invalid column name. This doesn't make any sense. That info is not supposed to be the column name but the data inserted into a column.

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with single quotes, double quotes, and backticks. I could be wrong. It still thinks the data I'm trying to insert is the column names.

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @user1548989 Fair enough. I reopened the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO delivery_comments (commentor, comment, jobno) VALUES ('$txtCommentor','$txtComment', '$jobno') ";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $txtCommentor = $_POST['txtCommentor'] //from form?>
<?php $txtComment = $_POST['txtComment'] //from form?>
<?php $jobno = $_GET['jobno'] //from URL?>

<?php
$params = array( $txtCommentor, $txtComment, $jobno);
//Query and connect
$query = "INSERT INTO delivery_comments (commentor, comment, jobno) VALUES (?,?,?) ";?>
<?php $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query,$params);?>
```

The above is the sanitized version of your query.

You should have much more success with that

Comment: I am insanely confused as to why I am passing the data to the sqlsrv_query twice. And what goes in the "?"

Comment: The question mark is replaced by the array. You ate passing an array of options rather than each one one at a tome